# Mixing Mold Resistant Drywall with Standard

Tags: drywall, painting, remodeling, patching-drywall

Really simple question.

I have a mix of 1/2” mold-resistant and standard drywall sheets remaining on a remodel. Is there any silly reason why I might not want to mix the two together where I don’t need mold-resistant? Is there some odd taping or finishing concern that can pop up?

Surface will be textured with a hopper to match existing then painted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've done that with left over drywall.  I tried to use the pieces in a closet.

If textured, I have found no difference in the final finish.

Go for it.

Comment: Thanks - new to drywall, so I didn’t want to find out after the fact that you don’t want to do that for some strange reason!

Comment: In bathrooms, it is not uncommon in older homes to find the Moisture resistant right next to the standard drywall right outside a shower or tub area.

Comment: As long as they're the same thickness, no problem!